# How to find out how many bits (minimum) will be sufficient to represent the undirected unweighted graph?

Tags: data-structures, graph

An undirected unweighted graph of n vertices (n > 1) is symmetrical across the diagonal. If a bit represents the presence of an edge. How many bits (minimum) will be sufficient to represent the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: (loops are not allowed)

---

Matrix for `N` nodes will have `N*N` cells.

We can ignore main diagonal so we are left with `N * N - N` cells.

Because matrix is symmetrical we can get rid of half of them, so we are left with `(N * N - N) / 2` cells

Every cell will be represented with a bit so we only need `(N * N - N) / 2` bits

---

Case 2: (loops are allowed)

---

Similar reasoning as above, yet we will need extra `N` bits for main diagonal.

So in total we would need `( N * N - N) / 2 + N` bits